# Epiphaneus: “Martyrdom of Peter and Paul”

Tags: church-history, reference-request

I’m researching a particular subject in Epiphanius’ writings and have found every often listed reference except one, despite a long, wearying search in every nook and cranny of Google.

This reference is entitled *Martyrium Petri et Pauli* in Latin, possibly (also) entitled *Martyrdom of Peter and Paul* in English.

Chapter 1 alone would suffice, but *I MUST see the actual text in the original Greek*, if possible. Regrettably, I have seen no further bibliographical details.

Comment: Are you certain the text is extant? You may need to make a trip to a research library.

Comment: Where do you see this reference?

Comment: Good people, so many thanks! At the moment I’m actually in dialogue with a scholar who’s a guru here. And he’s quickly alerted me to the fact that in my several similar references there’s room for confusion in that only the first of three works in sequence following the name Epiphanius are his. So now I need to search out either *Martyrdom of Peter and Paul* or *Martyrium Petri et Pauli*, with no other bibliographical details.

Answer (score 1):

The complete works of Epiphanius (as of the end of the 19th century) can be found in the [*Patrologia Graeca*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrologia_Graeca). His works constitute volumes 41 and 42, and part of 43. There are two "analytical" (i.e. topical) indices for his works: one for [volumes 41–42](https://books.google.com/books?id=C4P5eFG6Yg4C&pg=RA3-PA1103#v=onepage&q&f=false) and one for [volume 43](https://books.google.com/books?id=1OWZTTARIA0C&pg=RA1-PA637#v=onepage&q&f=false). I can't see a reference to "martyr", "Peter", or "Paul" in any applicable sense in either index. It appears that either this is a newly discovered work (though I don't see it in, for example, the Wikipedia article on Epiphanius), or there is a mis-attribution of some sort.